# Unable to save Fuchsia

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, flowers, transplanting

I have a small sized Fuchsia in a medium sized plant.
Even few days back, it was flowering.

Suddenly, for last few days (4 or 5 days) the leaves started drying out.
I thought I was over watering and I thought that may be the root has rotten.
So I changed the soil.

While changing I saw that the root is not rotten and the soil is in perfectly good condition (no pest or anything).
After repotting all the leaves are dropped and now there not a single leave in the plant.
I kept the plant hydrated (small water everyday).

Could anyone please help? I don't know why this plant is dying.

Here is the picture

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include pictures

Comment: @user33232 - added pics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that’s probably it for that plant.

The colour of the stems suggest to me that this is over watering. 
Basically, you drowned the roots and they probably rotted.

The reason seems that your compost has very little air filled porosity. The air available in the compost is almost as important as the compost itself. No drainage means that the water either stagnates or bakes and goes straight through.
The ideal compost mix, for most plant is 60% compost and 40% drainage such as grit.

You can try repotting again with that mix if you feel the roots might survive. Check how much rot you might have.

A note on Fuchsia:

They are very strong and hardy herbaceous plants. 
Mine return every year after hard pruning in January. 
We are experiencing a very long heat wave here in the UK and they still look fab. Only watered twice in 6 weeks

Comment: Hello. Thank you for the reply. I already repotted it previously. I have added a new image of roots. I am not sure if they are rotten. :( Thanks again.

Comment: @SrijaniGhosh yes. It looks rotted. You can still try a repot but make sure you use lots of grit. I’d go 50~50, even more. Good luck

Comment: Further advice: always know or research a plant’s habit and growing conditions in nature. That’s the best way for a plant to thrive “artificially” in our gardens and houses.

Comment: Thanks again :). I repotted it and trimmed it too. However, I wanted to know, is there anything else I can do? once I saved a plant (fittonia) by repotting and covering the remaining plant in plastic so that it have more humidity. Should I do something like this with this one too?

Comment: Yes. You could cover with a plastic bag to increase humidity. I would had bottom heat if you can too, like when taking softwood cuttings. However, I wouldn’t add anything else at this stage as mentioned below. Your plant is already under serious stress and doesn’t need anymore to deal with... but that’s my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to consider doing when transplanting plants is to use organic transplant shock reducing fertilizer (Sea Weed extract or Vitamin B-12 extract).

This is of course, in addition to checking the aeration of soil and root health like the @user33232 mentioned.